# Sharepoint - Missing ""Site Collection Administration" options

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We've recently set up Small Business Server 2008 and have a Sharepoint installation which was added during the SBS installation.

I'm trying to add a policy to a site collection as [described here](http://www.gk.id.au/2009/05/sharepoint-and-information-management.html)

However, the items listed under "Site Collection Administration" (in his first screenshot) are very different to mine. Specifically, I see:

Recycle bin
Site collection features
Site hierarchy
Portal site connection

Now my first assumption was a permissions issue but I was the one who set it up and my username already seems to be in the correct place for every permissions page I've found (Including the one accessible through Administrative Tools)

I'm not sure if there are other permissions I need to set or if we're missing / haven't enabled some modules.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SBS comes with Windows SharePoint Services (WSS) - not full Microsoft Office SharePoint Server (MOSS) - the screenshot you linked to is from a MOSS installation - the features you see are all that is available in a WSS installation.

Comment: That explains rather a lot. Thanks very much for the information